# How to retrieve response from Amazon SES?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have the code to verify email address in Amazon ses

```
<?php
$sesClient = SesClient::factory(array(
            'key'    => 'secret key',
            'secret' => 'secret',
            'profile' => 'user_name',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1'
        ));
$result = $sesClient->verifyEmailAddress(array('EmailAddress'=> $email));
?>
```

My output for $result is like this:

```
object(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model) {
    [protected] structure => null
    [protected] data => array()
}
```

I actually got verified email in the email id I have specified. My question is, how to check whether the function worked correctly using the response I have received? In earlier Amazon web services, they used `$result->is('Ok')` to verify the result. what function should I use now to check the result for success and failure of that function?

I've checked with the [amazon link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_verifyEmailAddress) and still can't find the function for successful response

Comment: question: what happens if you try to verify the email address `lolcat@example` a.k.a. an invalid email address? what response do you get?

Comment: @Michael I got this response `object(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model) {
 [protected] structure => null
 [protected] data => array()
}`

Comment: Do you get a different response if you use a valid email address?

Comment: so, it seems that data->ResponseMetaData->RequestId will be set on success and missing on error...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am getting the same response I've mentioned on question for every email address regardless of its validity

Comment: @Ganesh but I thought the data array is empty when you use an invalid email address? from your comment above: `[protected] data => array()` and on a valid address you get a data array that is not empty at all (i look at the example response in your question)

Comment: @Michael Response is same for both valid & invalid emailaddresses

Comment: ok, so you edited the question. in the last revision of the question there was a RequestId parameter in the response (`72acf8c2-e58b-11e3-976e-1174ece7b4e7`), where did you get that from?

Comment: @Michael Yeah, I've edited the question, the response which I stated earlier came from another function called sendEmail() & I received responseId in that. For the above mentioned function, I got the above stated output.

Comment: ok. is it possible to see the XML response? because i don't see how the XML response [as mentioned in the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_VerifyEmailIdentity.html) relates to the `toString` output of `$result`... (maybe the data is there, you just don't see it just by printing out `$result`)

Comment: Using Fiddler would help troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: @snowYetis Since the userid & secretkey is commerical,sorry, its not possible for me to fiddle this question

Comment: @Michael You've mentioned the earlier version of Amazon SES. The updated doc is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_verifyEmailAddress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at tests of aws-sdk-php found this:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/tests/Aws/Tests/Ses/Integration/IntegrationTest.php#L86

Maybe you can try:

```
$sesClient->verifyEmailAddress(array('EmailAddress'=> $email));
$sesClient->waitUntilIdentityExists(array('Identities' => array($email)));
$result = $sesClient->getIdentityVerificationAttributes(array('Identities' => array($email)));
if ('Success' === $result->getPath("VerificationAttributes/{$email}/VerificationStatus"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to use `verifyEmailIdentity` *not* `verifyEmailAddress`:

```
$result = $sesClient->verifyEmailIdentity(array('EmailAddress'=> $email));
```

As stated in the AWS documentation:

> The VerifyEmailAddress action is deprecated as of the May
>   15, 2012 release of Domain Verification. The VerifyEmailIdentity
>   action is now preferred.

• [**Further Reading**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_verifyEmailIdentity)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now how to check whether the mail is sent to particular subscriber or not? As I specified in question, what function have amazon replaced with $result->is('Ok')?

Comment: @Ganesh, From my understanding [verifyEmailIdentityResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_VerifyEmailIdentityResult.html) responds with an empty result that confirms the request completed successfully.  It appears that it's part of [VerifyEmailIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_VerifyEmailIdentity.html) and is returned from `VerifyEmailIdentityResponse`. The only mention of this seems to be in the two urls I've linked; the class documentation makes no reference to it that I've noticed.