# Array structure seemingly ignoring first key - why?

Tags: php

Could someone please explain what is happening here?

I run this:

```
$result = $client->getIdentityVerificationAttributes([
    'Identities' => $verifyemail
    ]);
```

FYI, it's an Amazon Web Services call (more info here if you think it is relevant: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-email-2010-12-01.html#verifyemailidentity)

And the `print_r` result looks like this:

```
Aws\Result Object
(
    [data:Aws\Result:private] => Array
        (
            [VerificationAttributes] => Array
                (
                    [warren@mydomain.com.au] => Array
                        (
                            [VerificationStatus] => Pending
                        )

                )

            [@metadata] => Array
                (
                    [statusCode] => 200
                    [effectiveUri] => https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
                    [headers] => Array
                        (
                            [x-amzn-requestid] => 01ff8101-dae0-11e6-bbd2-856fb04f68c9
                            [content-type] => text/xml
                            [content-length] => 564
                            [date] => Sun, 15 Jan 2017 05:03:52 GMT
                        )

                    [transferStats] => Array
                        (
                            [http] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

See the `VerificationStatus`? That's all I want so my question is this: why can I only get to that with this:

```
$result['VerificationAttributes'][$verifyemail[0]]['VerificationStatus']
```

I.e., why is the first key (`data:Aws\Result:private`) ignored - why can I **not** get the verification status if I add that key to the above path???

Comment: You have an object here with a private property, not an array. So that object probably provides a method to access that property.

Comment: @Rizier123, so because the beginning of the dump is not 'Array', but 'Aws\Result Object' it behaves as built? - Got it. Post your comment as an answer, because that's it :)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830383/how-to-retrieve-response-from-amazon-ses there is a possible $result->toArray() method you might be able to make use of as well.